# List of String and Value Duplicates

Tags: c#, database, list

I have db entity orderItems and class OrderCountet 
where i have method Counting to made statistic of the most popular products in my shop based on orderItems.

After code below i have output like this:

```
Name          Quantity
Chocapic       7
Bread          2
Chocapic       7
Bread          2
Cheese         3
```

I want to make this list without duplicates.
Because now output says that i have 14 chocapic in this List but i have only 7.
I was trying to search something how to achieve that but i only found HashSet.
Also distinct List solution but only for List of String or Integer.

```
    Public class Statistic
{

    //ProductName
    String Name {get: set;} 
    //quantity product
    Int quantity {get: set;}
       //class for counting
    and OrderCounter OrderCounter{get: set;}

}

public class OrderCounter

{
      private List<Statistic> list_statistic =new List<Statistic>();

public List<Statistic> List_statistic
{

     get{ return list_statistic ;}
}

 public void Counting()
{
       foreach(Order k in db.OrderItems)
    {
            int sum=0;
            Statistic temp =new Statistic();

        foreach(Product product in db.Products)
         {
               if(product.Id==k.productId
               {

                 sum+=sum+k.quantity;
               }
             temp.quantity=sum;
             temp.Name=k.Product.Name();
             list_statistic.Add(temp);
         }
    }

    if(orders.product.Id==product.Id)
    {
        sum+=suma +k.quantity;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: why not a `Dictionary<T, T2>`?

Comment: This isn't doing what you want either: `sum+=sum+k.quantity;`  You just need `sum+=k.quantity;`.

Comment: That's the least of your problems here though.  If you want help, take the time to make sure the code actually compiles/etc: [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: If you have a underlying db why wouldnt you let the db distinct your values? Thats more reasonable for me than doing it by hand afterwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try using the following `foreach` loop in the `Counting()` method,

```
        foreach (Order k in db.OrderItems)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            foreach (Product product in db.Products)
            {
                Statistic temp = new Statistic();
                if (product.Id == k.productId)
                {
                    sum += k.quantity;
                }
                temp.quantity = sum;
                temp.Name = k.Product.Name();
                if (!list_statistic.Exists(x => string.Compare(x.Name, temp.Name, true) == 0))
                {
                    list_statistic.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks ;) after little modification i achieve now i have to count only duplicates values.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you keep adding the same object to the list: `temp` is created once before the loop, and gets added multiple times.

Move this line inside the loop to fix the problem:

```
Statistic temp =new Statistic();
```

If you can, give `Statistics` a constructor that takes `name` and `quantity`, and make the object immutable by changing its setter's accessibility to `private`.

Answer (score 0):

this is working :)

```
public void Counting()
        {
            foreach (Order k in db.OrderItems)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                Statystyki temp = new Statystyki();
                foreach (Product product in db.Products)
                {

                    if (product.Id == k.productId)
                    {
                        sum += k.quantity;
                    }
                }

                temp.Nazwa = k.Product.Name;
                if (!lista_statystyk.Exists(x => string.Compare(x.Nazwa, temp.Nazwa, true) == 0))
                {

                    temp.suma = sum;
                    lista_statystyk.Add(temp);
                }
                else if (lista_statystyk.Exists(x => string.Compare(x.Nazwa, temp.Nazwa, true) == 0))
                {
                    temp.suma += sum;
                    lista_statystyk.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
```